# The I / O was aborted because of a thread end or an application request

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, ioexception

i have looked lots of topic about this but no result. Im building a programm, which automatically receives datafrom a measure device. I try to open/close the ComPort, sometimes it works but sometimes it throws an IOException when i close the Port. No mater what i do, this IoException still comes out.

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or
>   an application request.

I think, when i close the Comport while the program still receiving and working on data from the measure device, and that cause Exception. Or maybe because of the threading?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Pt340
{
    private bool _isConnected = false;

    public SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort
    {
        BaudRate = 19200,
        Parity = Parity.Odd,
        StopBits = StopBits.One,
        DataBits = 7,
        ReadTimeout = 500           
    };

    private  Dictionary<string, string> _status = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public  void Open()
    {
        try
        {
            _isConnected = true;
            ComPort.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Connection fail!");
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            _isConnected = false;
        }
    }
    public  void CLose()
    {
        _isConnected = false;

        if(ComPort.IsOpen)
        ComPort.Close();

    }
    private  void _command(string str)
    {
        _status = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        int temp = (int)str[0];
        _status.Add("RangeHex", temp.ToString("X"));
        temp = (int)str[6];
        _status.Add("FuncHex", temp.ToString("X"));
        // functions
        Dictionary<int, ArrayList> functions = new Dictionary<int, ArrayList>();

        //dict
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var dictArrayList = new ArrayList();
            Dictionary<string, string> nameDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, int[]> desimalDict = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
            Dictionary<string, string[]> unitsDict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
            Dictionary<string, double[]> mulDict = new Dictionary<string, double[]>();
            //temporate variable
            string nameTemp = "";
            int[] desimalTemp = new int[] { };
            string[] unitsTemp = new string[] { };
            double[] mulTemp = new double[] { };
            int hex = 0x00;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    nameTemp = @"Current A (auto)";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 3 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "A" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 1.0 };
                    hex = 0x30;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    nameTemp = @"Capacitance";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "nF", "nF", "uF", "uF", "uF", "mF", "mF", "mF" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 0.000000001, 0.000000001, 0.000001, 0.000001, 0.000001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001 };
                    hex = 0x36;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    nameTemp = @"Diode";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 4 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "V" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 1.0 };
                    hex = 0x31;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    nameTemp = @"Current A (manual)";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 3 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "A" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 1.0 };
                    hex = 0x39;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    nameTemp = @"Frequency / Duty";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "Hz", "Hz", "kHz", "kHz", "kHz", "MHz", "MHz", "MHz" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0 };
                    hex = 0x32;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    nameTemp = @"Voltage";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 4, 3, 2, 1, 2 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "V", "V", "V", "V", "mV" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.001 };
                    hex = 0x3b;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    nameTemp = @"Ohm";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "Ohm", "kOhm", "kOhm", "kOhm", "MOhm", "MOhm", "MOhm" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 1.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0 };
                    hex = 0x33;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    nameTemp = @"Auto uA current";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 2, 1 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "uA", "uA" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 0.000001, 0.000001 };
                    hex = 0x3d;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    nameTemp = @"Continuity";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 2 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "Ohm" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 1.0 };
                    hex = 0x35;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    nameTemp = @"Auto mA current";
                    desimalTemp = new int[] { 3, 2 };
                    unitsTemp = new string[] { "mA", "mA" };
                    mulTemp = new double[] { 0.001, 0.001 };
                    hex = 0x3f;
                    break;

            }
            nameDict.Add("Name", nameTemp); dictArrayList.Add(nameDict);
            desimalDict.Add("Desimal", desimalTemp); dictArrayList.Add(desimalDict);
            unitsDict.Add("Unit", unitsTemp); dictArrayList.Add(unitsDict);
            mulDict.Add("Mul", mulTemp); dictArrayList.Add(mulDict);
            functions.Add(hex, dictArrayList);
        }
        // status bits from byte 7

        _status.Add("Judge", (((int)str[7] & (1 << 3)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("Batt", (((int)str[7] & (1 << 1)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("OL", (((int)str[7] & (1 << 0)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        if ((((int)str[7] & (1 << 2)) != 0))
            _status.Add("Sign", "-");
        else
            _status.Add("Sign", "");
        //bit 8
        _status.Add("Max", (((int)str[8] & (1 << 3)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("Min", (((int)str[8] & (1 << 2)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("Rel", (((int)str[8] & (1 << 1)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        //bit 9
        _status.Add("UL", (((int)str[9] & (1 << 3)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("Pmax", (((int)str[9] & (1 << 2)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("Pmin", (((int)str[9] & (1 << 1)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        //bit 10
        _status.Add("DC", (((int)str[10] & (1 << 3)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("AC", (((int)str[10] & (1 << 2)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("Auto", (((int)str[10] & (1 << 1)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("VAHz", (((int)str[10] & (1 << 0)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        // bit 11
        _status.Add("VBar", (((int)str[11] & (1 << 1)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("Hold", (((int)str[11] & (1 << 1)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        _status.Add("LPF", (((int)str[11] & (1 << 0)) != 0 ? true : false).ToString());
        //
        if (functions.ContainsKey((int)str[6]))
        {
            var v = (Dictionary<string, string>)functions[(int)str[6]][0];
            _status.Add("Function", v["Name"]);
            int rangeIndex = (int)str[0] - 48;
            //unit
            string unit = "";
            try
            {
                var v2 = (Dictionary<string, string[]>)functions[(int)str[6]][2];
                unit = v2["Unit"][rangeIndex];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                unit = "?";
            }
            //decimal
            int dec;
            try
            {
                var v3 = (Dictionary<string, int[]>)functions[(int)str[6]][1];
                dec = v3["Desimal"][rangeIndex];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                dec = 0;
            }
            //mul
            double mul=0.0;
            try
            {
                var v4 = (Dictionary<string, double[]>)functions[(int)str[6]][3];
                mul = (double)v4["Mul"][rangeIndex];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                mul = 0;
            }
            _status.Add("Decimal", dec.ToString());
            _status.Add("Unit", unit.ToString());

            if (_status["Function"] == "Frequency / Duty")
                if (_status["Judge"] == "True")
                    _status["Function"] = "Frequency";
                else
                    _status["Function"] = "Duty";
            _status.Add("Division", Math.Pow(10, dec).ToString());
            _status.Add("RawNumber", _status["Sign"] + str.Substring(1, 5));
            Double.TryParse(str.Substring(1, 5), out double number);
            number = number / Math.Pow(10, dec);
            _status.Add("Digits", number.ToString());
            if (_status["Sign"] == "-")
                _status["Digits"] = (-number).ToString();
            _status.Add("Measurement", _status["Digits"] + _status["Unit"]);
            if (_status["OL"] == "True")
            {
                _status["OL"] = "OL";
                _status["Digits"] = "0";
            }
            Double.TryParse(_status["Digits"], out double num);
            _status.Add("Value", (num * mul).ToString());
        }

    }
    public string GetValue() { return _status["Value"]; }
    public string GetMeasurement() { return _status["Measurement"]; }
    public string GetFunction(){return _status["Function"];
    }
    public  void Translate()
    {

      _command(ComPort.ReadLine());// Exception here 




    }

}
```

> code in form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

namespace PeakTechApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Pt340 pt340 = new Pt340();
        delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string[] ArrayComPortsNames;
        ArrayComPortsNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        if (ArrayComPortsNames.Length == 0) return;
        Array.Sort(ArrayComPortsNames);
        foreach (var v in ArrayComPortsNames)
            cBoxCom.Items.Add(v);
        cBoxCom.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    private void cBoxCom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cBoxCom.Text = cBoxCom.SelectedText;
    }
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cBoxCom.Text)) { MessageBox.Show("Please chose one comport."); return; }
        if (btnConnect.Text == "Connect")
        {
            pt340.ComPort.PortName = cBoxCom.Text;
            pt340.Open();
            pt340.ComPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_Comport_DataReceived);
            btnConnect.Text = "Close";
        }
        else if(btnConnect.Text=="Close")
        {
            pt340.CLose();
            btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
        }
    }
    private void _Comport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        pt340.Translate();
        SetText(pt340.GetValue() + "\r\n"
                + pt340.GetMeasurement() + "\r\n" );

    }
    bool isClose = false;
    // show the output
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (rBox.InvokeRequired && isClose==false)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            rBox.Text += text;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        pt340.ComPort.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_Comport_DataReceived);
        pt340.CLose();
        isClose = true;
    }
    private void rBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rBox.SelectionStart = rBox.Text.Length;
        rBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see any threading in there.

Comment: im still student and  learning to code. that's just my thoughts. i think when the ComPort opens, it will automatically create a thread, isnt it?

Comment: " i think when the ComPort opens, it will automatically create a thread, isnt it?" What makes you think that? ( No it doesn't )

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `Translate` ? Do you actually open the port before?

Comment: I think that SerialPort utilizes its own thread while performing actions.
You should use the method InvokeRequired

Comment: "I think that SerialPort utilizes its own thread while performing actions." - Citation needed.

Comment: Apaprently, while receiving data it uses its own thread. I checked fast on : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It uses it's own EventLoop on a thread, yes. That's french docs, @FlorianMichel ;)

Comment: @TùngBill Do you make sure you always _close_ the port gracefully? On App Exit, On Stop Debugging, On Unexpected Exception ... _always_(!) ? If you leave a SerialPort opened, you'll run into many "strange" issues. Even if you close it, you need to wait for some time until you can try to successfully open it again. Another idea: Are you sure, you receive a valid newline? If not, ReadLine will block "forever".

Comment: Additionally, I recommend to set a reasonable read timeout.

Comment: im trying to update my code here, pls wait for me a sec

Comment: There's a whole mess of threading and buffering going on in the driver layers. Don't expect to be able to work with it serially. You should use DataReceived & ErrorReceived. I would wrap the whole thing up in a stream or a bunch of async methods.

Comment: can you tell me more details? i just get in coding for a shortime

Comment: @Fildor THANK YOUUUUUUUUUUUUUU. i got itttttttttttttttttt. you are my hero bro. i forgot to use this when i close the comport.-->>>> pt340.ComPort.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(_Comport_DataReceived);